# Parametric equations of lines with one parameter being zero

Tags: parametric, curves

Parameterize a line from $(1,0)$ to $(-1,0)$. Positivly oriented.

The answer says $x=x$, $y=0$.

My question is, why didn't the formula $r(t)=(1-t)(x_1,y_1)+t(x_2,y_2)$ work?

Comment: It would work to. It gives $r(t) = (1-2t, 0)$. For $t=0$ it would give $(1,0)$ and for $t=1$ it would give $(-1,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

it works $$\vec{x}=[1,0]+t[-2,0]$$ and $t$ is a real number